# Upload a file more than 2 mb to Document Library using Java script in Share point

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepointdocumentlibrary, sharepoint-jsom

I am uploading an excel file to a folder in Document library using Javascript in share point.
IT is properly uploading if the excel size is less than 2 MB and if the excel size is more than 2 MB my code is going to the exception.
Please help on how to upload a file which is more than 2 Mb in share point using Javascript.
This is the [Link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-uploads-document-in-document-library-using-jsom-in-sharepoint-2013-o365) I followed.

```
   function uploadFile(arrayBuffer, fileName )
        {
            //Get Client Context,Web and List object.
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
            var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
            var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('MyFolder');
            //Convert the file contents into base64 data
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
            var i, length, out = '';
            for (i = 0, length = bytes.length; i < length; i += 1)
            {
                out += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
            }
            var base64 = btoa(out);
            //Create FileCreationInformation object using the read file data
            var createInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
            createInfo.set_content(base64);
            createInfo.set_url(fileName);
            //Add the file to the library
            var uploadedDocument = oList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(createInfo)

      listItem = uploadedDocument.get_listItemAllFields();
      listItem.set_item('Title', 'Some Title');
          listItem.update();

            //Load client context and execcute the batch
      clientContext.load(uploadedDocument,'ListItemAllFields');
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.QuerySuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.QueryFailure));
     element.value = '';
    document.getElementById("getTitle").value = "";

    }

  function QuerySuccess()
  {
 //var id = uploadedDocument.get_listItemAllFields();
    //here we can get all the fields
    console.log('File Uploaded Successfully.');
    swal("File Uploaded Successfully.");


}
  function QueryFailure(sender, args)
  {
    console.log('Request failed with error message - ' + args.get_message() + ' . Stack Trace - ' + args.get_stackTrace());
    swal(args.get_message());
}
```

Thanks for the Help.

Comment: And the exception being thrown is?

Comment: @abestrad, the exception is "The request message is too big. The server does not allow messages larger than 2097152 bytes."- Is there any way I can Increase this size to 10 MB, Thanks

Comment: Seems to be duable, but all docs examples are using APIs for C#,